# Install winston on julia

Tags: julia

I' ve got julia installed on mac 10.7, but unable to install Winston package.

That's what happens:

`Pkg.add("Winston")
   ERROR: unknown dependency for NIfTI: StrPack
   ....`

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

The julia-users@googlegroups.com list is a much better place for this. Also see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/3027. In short, do `Pkg.update()` and try again.